# Type of char multiply by another char

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, integer-promotion

What is the type of the result of a multiplication of two chars in C/C++?

```
unsigned char a = 70;
unsigned char b = 58;
cout << a*b << endl; // prints 4060, means no overflow
cout << (unsigned int)(unsigned char)(a*b) << endl; // prints 220, means overflow
```

I expect the result of multiplying two number of type T (e.g., char, short, int) becomes T. It seems it is `int` for `char` because `sizeof(a*b)` is 4.

I wrote a simple function to check the size of the result of the multiplication:

```
template<class T>
void print_sizeof_mult(){
  T a;
  T b;
  cout << sizeof(a*b) << endl;
}
```

`print_sizeof_mult<char>()`, `print_sizeof_mult<short>()`, and `print_sizeof_mult<int>()` are 4 and `print_sizeof_mult<long>()` is 8.

Are these result only for my particular compiler and machine architecture? Or is it documented somewhere that what type is the output of basic operations in C/C++?

Comment: The type of multiplying two `T`is `int` if all the possible values of `T` are in range for `int`.  The C++ Standard documents the behaviour.  C and C++ are different languages, in C your code would left-shift a variable called `cout`

Comment: @M.M: actually, in C the compiler would start complaining at `template<`.

Comment: See "integral promotion": http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the C++ Standard (4.5 **Integral promotions**)

> 1 A prvalue of an integer type other than bool, char16_t, char32_t, or
>   wchar_t whose integer conversion rank (4.13) is less than the rank of
>   int can be converted to a prvalue of type int if int can represent all
>   the values of the source type; otherwise, the source prvalue can be
>   converted to a prvalue of type unsigned int.

and (5 Expressions)

> 10 Many binary operators that expect operands of arithmetic or
>   enumeration type cause conversions and yield result types in a similar
>   way. The purpose is to yield a common type, which is also the type of
>   the result. This pattern is called **the usual arithmetic conversions**,
>   which are deﬁned as follows:

....

> - Otherwise, **the integral promotions (4.5) shall be performed on both 
>     operands**.61 Then the following rules shall be applied to the promoted
>     operands:

and at last (5.6 Multiplicative operators)

> 2 The operands of * and / shall have arithmetic or unscoped
>   enumeration type; the operands of % shall have integral or unscoped
>   enumeration type. **The usual arithmetic conversions are performed on
>   the operands** and determine the type of the result.

Types `char` and `short` have conversion ranks that are less than the rank of the type `int`.

Comment: To remember these rules is useful to think at `char` and `short` as "storage types", i.e. smaller types that only come into play when you store your data in memory (and you want to save some); when performing operations they don't really exist, once the data is in the registers the arithmetic is done in the full registers size (which is what `int` originally was - a value corresponding to the machine register).